# Tiling in InDesign: See guides where the page will be cut?

Tags: adobe-indesign, layout

I am using InDesign (for the first time) to create a big scientific poster that will be printed on several A3 sheets.

To achieve this, I am intending to use the automatic "tiling" function that can be checked upon printing in ID. However, when designing my poster, I would like to know where the cuts between the pages will be. I want to place my pictures so that they are not being cut by printing on two pages.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: possible workaround, if you do not want your images being cut anyway (which are the most like candidates to cross page boundaries): just design it as a multipage document from the start?

Answer (score 1):

Tile sizes are entirely dependent upon the "page" size of your printer. You would need to draw your own guides.

In addition, most tiling features *automatically* generate an overlap of tiles to make reassembly easier. Although You may have an option in InDesign to manually configure the overlap (in the `Setup` options):

[image]

Whether or not that is there may depend upon your printer driver.

So if you don't want some images to "overlap on two sheets" you'll need to keep the images away from your tile edges, in some cases, leaving a considerable tile margin.

Since every printer is different, you may be best to run some basic trial and error prints.... set something up to tile 4 times and draw some basic shapes so you can see the overlap in your specific environment and adjust.  Don't waste a lot of ink/toner. All you really need to do is draw a square with an X through it - unfilled, with a decent weight stroke - in the center where your 4 tiles will overlap and cross the middle.

[image]

That should give you enough of an indicator about the tile overlap and margins necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Sounds complicated though. Maybe it is easier to just print it as is and try to assemble it carefully so the overlaps don't become too disturbing. Do you have any experience of that?